# How can I make the bounce height constant when the game is gradually getting faster?

Tags: c++, sdl

My main character is a ball that bounces forever at the same force.
But I having difficulties finding the right way of bouncing at the same height as the game is increasing speed. Basically, here's my formula.

by the way, I'm using C++ and SDL2 so the Y axis is POSITIVE going down and NEGATIVE going up:

every frame, I'm adding the Yvelocity to the ball. Then I add the gravity to the velocity for gravity effect:

```
ballY += Yvelocity
Yvelocity += gravity
if(Yvelocity >= maxVelocity)
{
   Yvelocity = maxVelocity
}
```

Then whenever I hit the ground, I do this to bounce the ball

```
Yvelocity = bounceForce; // -10 for example
```

Everything works great. But I want to make the game faster and faster. So every specific time I do this:

```
bounceForce += bounceForce * multiplier;
gravity += gravity * multiplier;
maxVelocity += gravity * multiplier;
...
//increase other object's speed too
```

The game speed is indeed getting faster but the bounce of the ball is also getting higher.

It looks like I have to increase the **gravity** more than **bounceForce**. So I tried doing this:

```
bounceForce += bounceForce * multiplier;
gravity += gravity * (multiplier * 1.5f); ///////    <-------------------------
maxVelocity += gravity * multiplier;
...
//increase other object's speed too
```

That works fine at the beginning. But will likely do the same problem as the time goes by(bounces higher).

I think the more the **Yvelocity** is increasing, the more the **gravity**'s multiplier has to increase too. Because the ball is getting lighter every increase of speed.

But I really can't find the right formula for that, of how I can make the ball bounce faster and faster **but** at the same height. Because it's not ideal for my game to increase speed then the ball is in constant speed. Sorry I'm a newbie in game programming. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) Why is there a `maxVelocity` limit? That'll make the bounces feel unnatural. 
2) When it hits the ground `Yvelocity = bounceForce;` seems wrong. `Yvelocity = -Yvelocity;` would feel more natual.

Comment: @TedLyngmo. Yes. tnx for the pointers. But it works well in my case.:
1) because I'm setting my **maxVelocity** as a limiter to **Yvelocity** so that it will control the natural fall of the ball.
2) Yvelocity = bounceForce; works also. because in my case, my bounceForce is a negative number. And I'll add **gravity** to that negative number every frame until it reaches positive number(in that case, the ball will fall).

Comment: `maxVelocity` should then be replaced by a counter force (like air resistance) that increases with higher velocity. That will make the limiting smooth. Setting `Yvelocity = bounceForce` (a speed equal to a force) doesn't make sense. If your [Coefficient of restitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_restitution) is `1` (the ball should bounce up to the same height forever), then `Yvelocity = -Yvelocity;` is what you want.

Comment: Yes. I get  it now. You are right.Thanks. I'll try that.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to make things “the same, only faster” is to increase your **time step** between frames.  Of course, you then have to make explicit all the places where you *should* have such a `dt` but have hardcoded it to 1.  (Finding invisible code is always fun.)

The obvious places are of course the `+=`s at the beginning of your code (sketch); your dynamics may include more if they’re complicated enough.  (Also note that your equations will become significantly inaccurate with a very large time step; you may want to make `dt` *smaller* (at first) and run more than one **physics** cycle per frame of animation.)

Comment: Thanks. But right now, I don't know how to implement the delta time because I'm just starting out. So for now I'm just using the passing frame. (moving N pixel per FRAME)  But I'll look into that. Thanks again.

Comment: @RobinOrbita: Pixels/frame is just pixels/time (change only according to physics) multiplied by time/frame (which is the time step that you change).  Algebra!